# How to apply Javascript click function to elements without class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, function

Currently I use:

```
$(':submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    $.ajax( {
        //Handle forms in ajax
    });
});
```

To handle all forms on a website, as 95% of forms are handled in ajax. This saves me having to apply it to a class and then having to add that class to every form.

My issue now is that 2 forms need to be handled without ajax to work correctly. So how would I apply this same function to all submit inputs apart from 2 with a particular class without hardcoding those specific elements in the function? Is this even possible? Is there a negative selector of this type?

I chose this approach as most forms use ajax submission, so please don't suggest targetting a class unless you're sure there isn't an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not()` in the selector:

```
$(':submit:not(.specialclass)').click(...)
```

You could also put the class in the form:

```
$('form:not(.specialclass)').submit(function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is the answer.  Note that "not" as a selector is relatively slow.  But, nowadays, who cares?

Comment: It only has to be done once, when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Lotus That's micro-optimizations. You better care about reflows and repaints than any of this. If you care about such optimizations you may just as well not use jQuery at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':submit:not([data-standard-sumbit])')...


<form>
    <button type="submit" data-standard-submit>Submit</button>   
</form>
```

However, it's usually better to bind to form `submit` events rather than to submit button `click` events.

Therefore:

```
$('form:not([data-standard-submit])').submit(...)

<form data-standard-submit></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's one specific class on the elements you don't want to process, you can use `.not()` to remove them from the jQuery object:

```
$(':submit').not(".yourClass").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    $.ajax( {
        //Handle forms in ajax
    });
});
```

If you're looking to avoid any form object that has any class name, then you can do this:

```
$(':submit').click(function(event) {
    if (this.className) {
         return;    // do nothing and let default action happen if there's a class name
    }
    event.preventDefault(); //Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    $.ajax( {
        //Handle forms in ajax
    });
});
```